# LICEcap - It is possible to blur or hide only specific part of the screen when creating the GIF

Tags: screen-capture

I want to create a GIF file using LICEcap. I have an email address which is opens from the popup in the screen and I don't want to show that in the GIF.

Is it possible that, can I blur or hide the email address alone from the GIF.

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

Do it in post-processing, e.g. with [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/), select a region with the mouse and then blur it (from the *Image effects* menu,  <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>, select one of the blurring tools).

Comment: The option you were provided was working for the Image file only, for the GIF file the options under the _Images -> Effects_ were disabled. Version is `4.42 32 bit`

Comment: Save the GIF from Irfan View in another format. Modify the JPEG, BMP or whatever. Then save it in IrfanView as GIF.